# Is using an Audit Table in Postgres to create triggers for NOTIFY/LISTEN a good idea?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, triggers, audit

So I have a postgres database that I have installed an audit table - source https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus

Now my question is as follows:

I have been wanting to create a sort of stream that notifies me of any changes that have been made by any application that has access to my DB. Now, I know that I can create a trigger and a pub/sub via pg but that will take up performance time and that is something that can become significant as the DB scales.

So instead of slowing the actual DB I was wondering if I were to do the same NOTIFY/LISTEN functionality I would've on the main tables but instead install it on the audit tables.

Has anyone ever done this? If so what have you experienced, pros? cons?. Or if anyone knows why I should or should not do this can you please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Via `NOTIFY/LISTEN`, the PRO-s:**

Light communications with the server, no need to pull for the data changes.

**Via `NOTIFY/LISTEN`, the CON-s:**

The practice shows that it is not sufficient just to set it up and listen for the events, because every so often the channel goes down, due to various communication problems. For a serious system you would need to put in place an additional monitoring service that can verify that your listeners are still operating, and if not - destroy the existing ones and create new ones. This can be tricky, and you probably won't find a good example of doing it.

**Via scheduled data pulls, PRO-s:**

- Simplicity - you just check for the data change according to the schedule;
- Reliability - there is nothing to break there, once the pull implementation is working.

**Via scheduled data pulls, CON-s:**

Additional traffic for the server, depending on how quickly you need to see the data change, and how would that interfere (if at all) with other requests to the server.